# WSO2 Service Providers not Populating in API Manager UI but it is Reading it from Database (RDS - postgres)

Tags: amazon-web-services, wso2, wso2-api-manager

While configuring fresh installs of wso2 API-Manager and Identity server, we have encountered this issue. Identity providers added through the API UI will populate in the IS UI, but service providers added through the IS console do not appear on API.

The two servers are running on EC2 instances with all traffic opened between them and we have verified on a different installation that the certs and keystores being used should not be causing any problems. We have not seen any specific connection refused issues in the logs, either, and the tcpdump shows that the two servers are communicating back and forth with each other. Using the working installation as a reference, there also does not appear to be any discrepancies from the deployment.tomls.

Both EC2s share the same RDS postgres database, but what is interesting is that if you try to manually add the service provider in the API UI, it will say that a provider with the same name already exists (meaning that it is reaching out to the database and finding the providers created in IS but it's still not populating them in the list in API console).

We've really been stumped by this one so any help would be greatly appreciated. Even trace/debug logs have not been helpful, but just let me know of any screenshots that could aid in remedying this problem. Thank you.

**Edits:**
WSO2 AM is version 3.1.0, WSO2 IS is version 5.10.0.
Both shared_db and the am_dbs are shared across both instances

deployment.toml for IS

```
[server]
hostname = 
node_ip = "127.0.0.1"
base_path = "https://$ref{server.hostname}:${carbon.management.port}"
serverDetails = "WSO2 IS as KM 5.10.0"
mode = "single"
userAgent = "WSO2 IS as KM 5.10.0"

[super_admin]
username = 
password = 
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"
[user_store.properties]
IsEmailUserName = false
MaxRoleNameListLength = 101
SharedGroupEnabled = false
UsernameJavaRegEx = "[a-zA-Z0-9@._\\+-|//]{3,50}$"
UsernameJavaScriptRegEx = "^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$"
UsernameWithEmailJavaScriptRegEx = "[a-zA-Z0-9@._+-|//]{3,50}$"
UserRolesCacheEnabled = false



[database.apim_db]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://wso2_am?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true&amp;"
username = 
password = 
driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"

[database.shared_db]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://wso2_shared?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true&amp;"
username = 
password = 
driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"

[database.config]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://wso2_shared?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true&amp;"
username = 
password = 
driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"

[database.user]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://wso2_user?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true&amp;"
username = 
password = 
driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"

[realm_manager]
data_source = "WSO2USER_DB"

[database.apim_db.pool_options]
 maxActive = "80"
 maxWait = "60000"
 minIdle = "5"
 testOnBorrow = true
 validationQuery="SELECT 1; COMMIT"
 validationInterval="30000"
 defaultAutoCommit=true
[database.shared_db.pool_options]
 maxActive = "80"
 maxWait = "60000"
 minIdle = "5"
 testOnBorrow = true
 validationQuery="SELECT 1; COMMIT"
 validationInterval="30000"
 defaultAutoCommit=true


[keystore.primary]
name = "wso2carbon.jks"
password = "wso2carbon"

[[event_listener]]
id = "mutual_tls_authenticator"
type = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.handler.AbstractIdentityHandler"
name = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handler.clientauth.mutualtls.MutualTLSClientAuthenticator"
order = "158"
enable = false
ssl_enabled_protocols = ["TLSv1.2"]

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://localhost:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://localhost:9711"]
type = "loadbalance"
[admin_service.wsdl]
enable= true
[tenant_mgt]
enable_email_domain= true
[identity_mgt_account_suspension]
use_identity_claims = false

[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Production and Sandbox"
type = "hybrid"
description = "This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic."
service_url = 
username= 
password= 
display_in_api_console = true
ws_endpoint="ws://${carbon.local.ip}:9099"
https_endpoint=
[apim.oauth_config]
revoke_endpoint = 
[apim.key_manager]
service_url = 
username = 
password = 

[apim.jwt]
enable = true
encoding = "base64" # base64,base64url
generator_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.JWTGenerator"
claim_dialect = "http://wso2.org/claims"
header = "X-JWT-Assertion"
signing_algorithm = "SHA256withRSA"
enable_user_claims = true
claims_extractor_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.token.DefaultClaimsRetriever"
[transport.http.properties]
compression = "off"

[transport.https.properties]
compression = "off"
```

deployment.toml for APIM

```
[server]
hostname = 
node_ip = "127.0.0.1"
#offset=0
serverDetails = "WSO2 IS as KM 5.10.0"
mode = "single" #single or ha
base_path = "${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}"
#discard_empty_caches = false
server_role = "default"
userAgent = "WSO2 IS as KM 5.10.0"

[super_admin]
username = 
password = 
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"

[database.apim_db]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://wso2_am?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true&amp;"
username = 
password = 
driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"

[database.shared_db]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://wso2_shared?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true&amp;"
username = 
password = 
driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"

[database.apim_db.pool_options]
maxActive = "80"
maxWait = "60000"
minIdle = "5"
testOnBorrow = true
validationQuery = "SELECT 1; COMMIT"
validationInterval = "30000"
defaultAutoCommit = true

[database.shared_db.pool_options]
maxActive = "80"
maxWait = "60000"
minIdle = "5"
testOnBorrow = true
validationQuery = "SELECT 1; COMMIT"
validationInterval = "30000"
defaultAutoCommit = true

[database.config]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://wso2_shared?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true&amp;"
username = 
password = 
driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"

[database.user]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://wso2_user?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true&amp;"
username = 
password = 
driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"

[keystore.tls]
file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "wso2carbon"
alias =  "wso2carbon"
key_password =  "wso2carbon"

#[keystore.primary]
#file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
#type =  "JKS"
#password =  "wso2carbon"
#alias =  "wso2carbon"
#key_password =  "wso2carbon"

#[keystore.internal]
#file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
#type =  "JKS"
#password =  "wso2carbon"
#alias =  "wso2carbon"
#key_password =  "wso2carbon"

[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Production and Sandbox"
type = "hybrid"
display_in_api_console = true
description = "This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic."
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true
service_url = 
username= 
password= 
ws_endpoint = 
wss_endpoint = 
http_endpoint = 
https_endpoint = 

[apim.cache.gateway_token]
enable = false
#expiry_time = "900s"

#[apim.cache.resource]
#enable = true
#expiry_time = "900s"

#[apim.cache.km_token]
#enable = false
#expiry_time = "15m"

#[apim.cache.recent_apis]
#enable = false

#[apim.cache.scopes]
#enable = true

#[apim.cache.publisher_roles]
#enable = true

#[apim.cache.jwt_claim]
#enable = true
#expiry_time = "15m"

#[apim.cache.tags]
#expiry_time = "2m"

#[apim.analytics]
#enable = false
#store_api_url = "https://localhost:7444"
#username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
#event_publisher_type = "default"
#event_publisher_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher"
#publish_response_size = true

#[[apim.analytics.url_group]]
#analytics_url =["tcp://analytics1:7611","tcp://analytics2:7611"]
#analytics_auth_url =["ssl://analytics1:7711","ssl://analytics2:7711"]
#type = "loadbalance"

#[[apim.analytics.url_group]]
#analytics_url =["tcp://analytics1:7612","tcp://analytics2:7612"]
#analytics_auth_url =["ssl://analytics1:7712","ssl://analytics2:7712"]
#type = "failover"

[apim.key_manager]
service_url = 
username = 
password = 
#pool.init_idle_capacity = 50
#pool.max_idle = 100
#key_validation_handler_type = "default"
#key_validation_handler_type = "custom"
#key_validation_handler_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.DefaultKeyValidationHandler"

#[apim.idp]
#authorize_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/oauth2/authorize"
#oidc_logout_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/oidc/logout"

[apim.jwt]
enable = true
encoding = "base64" # base64,base64url
generator_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.JWTGenerator"
claim_dialect = "http://wso2.org/claims"
header = "X-JWT-Assertion"
signing_algorithm = "SHA256withRSA"
enable_user_claims = true
claims_extractor_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.token.DefaultClaimsRetriever"

[apim.oauth_config]
#enable_outbound_auth_header = false
#auth_header = "Authorization"
revoke_endpoint = 
#enable_token_encryption = false
#enable_token_hashing = false

[apim.devportal]
url = 
#enable_application_sharing = false
#if application_sharing_type, application_sharing_impl both defined priority goes to application_sharing_impl
#application_sharing_type = "default" #changed type, saml, default #todo: check the new config for rest api
#application_sharing_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.SAMLGroupIDExtractorImpl"
#display_multiple_versions = false
#display_deprecated_apis = false
#enable_comments = true
#enable_ratings = true
#enable_forum = true

[apim.cors]
allow_origins = "*"
allow_methods = ["GET","PUT","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS"]
allow_headers = ["authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Content-Type","SOAPAction","apikey"]
allow_credentials = false

#[apim.throttling]
#enable_data_publishing = true
#enable_policy_deploy = true
#enable_blacklist_condition = true
#enable_persistence = true
#throttle_decision_endpoints = ["tcp://localhost:5672","tcp://localhost:5672"]

#[apim.throttling.blacklist_condition]
#start_delay = "5m"
#period = "1h"

#[apim.throttling.jms]
#start_delay = "5m"

#[apim.throttling.event_sync]
#hostName = "0.0.0.0"
#port = 11224

#[apim.throttling.event_management]
#hostName = "0.0.0.0"
#port = 10005

#[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
#traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://localhost:9611","tcp://localhost:9611"]
#traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://localhost:9711","ssl://localhost:9711"]
#type = "loadbalance"

#[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
#traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://localhost:9611","tcp://localhost:9611"]
#traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://localhost:9711","ssl://localhost:9711"]
#type = "failover"

#[apim.workflow]
#enable = false
#service_url = "https://localhost:9445/bpmn"
#username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
#callback_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/api/am/admin/v0.16/workflows/update-workflow-status"
#token_endpoint = "https://localhost:${https.nio.port}/token"
#client_registration_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/client-registration/v0.16/register"
#client_registration_username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#client_registration_password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"

#data bridge config
#[transport.receiver]
#type = "binary"
#worker_threads = 10
#session_timeout = "30m"
#keystore.file_name = "$ref{keystore.tls.file_name}"
#keystore.password = "$ref{keystore.tls.password}"
#tcp_port = 9611
#ssl_port = 9711
#ssl_receiver_thread_pool_size = 100
#tcp_receiver_thread_pool_size = 100
#ssl_enabled_protocols = ["TLSv1","TLSv1.1","TLSv1.2"]
#ciphers = ["SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5","SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"]

#[apim.notification]
#from_address = "APIM.com"
#username = "APIM"
#password = "APIM+123"
#hostname = "localhost"
#port = 3025
#enable_start_tls = false
#enable_authentication = true

#[apim.token.revocation]
#notifier_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.events.TokenRevocationNotifierImpl"
#enable_realtime_notifier = true
#realtime_notifier.ttl = 5000
#enable_persistent_notifier = true
#persistent_notifier.hostname = "https://localhost:2379/v2/keys/jti/"
#persistent_notifier.ttl = 5000
#persistent_notifier.username = "root"
#persistent_notifier.password = "root"

[[event_handler]]
name="userPostSelfRegistration"
subscriptions=["POST_ADD_USER"]

[service_provider]
sp_name_regex = "^[\\sa-zA-Z0-9._-]*$"

[database.local]
url = "jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"

[admin_service.local]
enable = true
```

Comment: Can you share the API Manager and Identity Server versions? Also, can you share whether the SHARED_DB and AM_DBs are shared across both products?

Comment: @Athiththan please see the edits

Comment: Can you specify whether you are using WSO2 IS 5.10.0 with APIM or WSO2 IS-KM 5.10.0 with APIM? WSO2 IS and WSO2 IS-KM are two different distributions.

Comment: Apologies, we are using IS-KM

Comment: What happens when you create a new Service Provider from the APIM side and view it on the IS side? Also, can you perform a server restart and check whether the SPs are listed? And do you see any WARN or ERROR traces in the logs of both products?

Comment: Service providers created from APIM do not appear on IS. Reboots do not affect the SP listings on either side. We get some warnings in the carbon logs regarding valid certs but the certs we have were tested on another installation and worked fine.

Comment: Can you share the TOML configurations (mask the sensitive information)? I believe that you are trying to add the SPs via the Carbon console and correct me if wrong. Also, share the Postgres version. My main suspect is that the DBs are not created properly or shared across.

Comment: Gimme a little while and I'll send you the TOML configs via chat. We are adding the SPs via console, is there a better way to add them? I also suspect that it may be a DB issue, we are running postgres 13 but have also tested on postgres 11 (with same configs) and encountered the same issue.

Comment: Sure. Adding the SP via the Carbon console is the preferred way.

Comment: @Athiththan I went ahead and added the tomls to the original post

Comment: Can you fill the TOMLs with Dummy DB names (same across both), so that I can cross-check whether the DB configurations are properly made?

Comment: I believe they're all there (if you scroll the window to the right). Am I missing any?

Comment: The DB configurations are only having the `jdbc:postgresql://`. If you can specify any Dummy DB names for each (apim, shared, config, and um), then I can correlate the configurations. As of now, the presented DB configurations are having only the connection URL as `jdbc:postgresql://`

Comment: Ok, I found an issue. You have configured UM DB separately in both products. But, you have mentioned using the `WSO2USER_DB` as the `realm_manager` in only WSO2 IS-KM. Can you make the same change in APIM TOML and restart the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the shared TOML configurations, a separate UM DB has been configured in both WSO2 IS-KM and API Manager servers. However, only the IS-KM is configured to use the `WSO2USER_DB` with the following configurations

```
[realm_manager]
data_source = "WSO2USER_DB"
```

Add the same configuration to the API Manager's TOML and restart the server.

The `realm_manager` configuration specifies which DB to use to store Users and Role information. So as of present, the IS-KM uses the UM DB to store the Users and roles whereas the API Manager is using the SHARED DB to store them. When you create an SP, an Application Role is also created along with it. As both APIM and IS-KM are using two different DBs to store the Users and Roles information (due to missing `realm_manager` configuration), the SPs are not getting visible on either side.